# The CiviCRM public extensions directory at https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.52.3|cms=WordPress could not be contacted

Tags: extension

We have the following message this morning ...
The CiviCRM public extensions directory at [https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.52.3|cms=WordPress](https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.52.3%7Ccms=WordPress) could not be contacted - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests
Can someone please explain what is it about? Many Thanks!